# VBA PPT AddEffects to Pictures Inconsistently Applies Effects

Tags: vba, image, formatting, powerpoint, intermittent

I am getting really frustrated. I have code that works, as in it literally does what it says it will do, however, it doesn't always correctly read my images on the slides as images. I even went so far as naming them all "Picture" and using it as a variable. It actually worked for a second but then 5 pictures in it stopped working again.

This is the code and it DOES work:

```
With shp.Fill.PictureEffects
    Dim eff As PictureEffect
    Set eff = .Insert(msoEffectSharpenSoften)
    eff.EffectParameters(1).Value = 1
End With
```

Why will this block of code not work on all of my images? Even when it throws the error it WILL sharpen the image as intended, but then stop??? I do not understand the problem or what a possible fix might be. This is literally the last bit of my work process that I need to solve...

For the record, I have code that will adjust the Height, Width, and center the image perfectly on the slide with no issues whatsoever, code that will put images in a placeholder and then format text... but for some reason THIS block of code won't work...

I have also tried deleting the image, manually reuploading it using the Insert Picture function in the program and it **still** doesn't work??? Is it possible this has something to do with the fact I am using PowerPoint 2013?

I tested it a different way by changing the picture format, it seemed like it was working but it didn't. Whether I automate it, whether I insert picture, no matter what I do, whether it's in a pre positioned container or not, this line of code refuses to work. Why are my images, in both PNG and JPEG format not being accepted by PowerPoint VBA?

Comment: >> Even when it throws the error << What error? What's the exact text?

Comment: Method can only be used by Pictures and OLE format objects. Something to that effect.

Comment: The error's occurring at your end; surely you can be a bit more accurate than "Something to that effect".   "This member can only be accessed for a picture or an OLE object" maybe? I can produce that if I run your code on an Enhanced Metafile or even an image copy/Pasted as Enhanced Metafile.

Comment: Yeah, so WHY is that happening? More importantly how do I fix it?